# Blindly choosing a ball from a bag

Tags: lateral-thinking, probability

You are blindfolded. You are handed a bag and told that there are three balls and two cubes, all of which are the same size and are equally likely to be chosen. You blindly choose one of the items from the bag. What is the probability that you choose a ball?

Comment: That depends on how many objects are actually in the bag, and how many of them are actually balls, regardless of what I was *told.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the answer is:

> 1

because:

> I assumed that you choose by touching the objects.

Comment: But what if I happen to like cubes?

Comment: Cube supremacy.